# How to filter an array based on 2 values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have an array containing multiple rowsets, including type, title and description....i need to filter the array and display only those rowsets based on type = "education" and type = "experience".

`foreach () { if (type = 'experience') ..do something / else ... do something else}` ?

Comment: Where is the array? Can you post a var_dump/print_r of that array?

Comment: Are you getting the array from database query

Comment: This old page has been closed by a later asked question because the quality of the [mcve] is far superior there and the page contains more modern advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
function myfilter($row){
    return ($row['type']=='experience'|| $row['type']=='education'); 
}
$result = array_filter($input_array, 'myfilter');
```

array_filter function preserves the keys of the original array. if you dont want this behavior use [array_values](http://php.net/array_values)

```
$result = array_values(array_filter($input_array, 'myfilter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(array('type'=>'experience','title'=>'xyz','des'=>'dfasdasdasdas'),
        array('type'=>'education','title'=>'xddfdfyz','des'=>'dfasdasdasdas'),
    array('type'=>'dsad','title'=>'afdf','des'=>'dfasdasdasdas'),
    array('type'=>'education','title'=>'gfdsfr','des'=>'dfasdasdasdas'));

foreach($array as $value){
    if($value['type'] == 'experience'){
        //do your stuff
    }else if ($value['type'] == 'education'){
        //do your stuff
    }else{
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

assuming your array sructure as shown,You can change foreach loops if condition as

```
 if($value['type'] == 'experience' || $value['type'] == 'education'){
//do your stuff
}else{
//do your stuff
}
```